# How to deal with posts that are helpful but strongly opinionated?

Tags: discussion

Refering to the question here : [using purrr::walk to instate multiple event observers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564632/using-purrrwalk-to-instate-multiple-event-observers)

The original answer was explicit in its use of language and in condemning a high profile developer of the tidyverse suite in R (Hadley Wickham). Understandibly some people of his development team took offense and flagged it. They also started a discussion under the post (again understandibly) which was clearly a culture clash.

I took the liberty to edit out all the (strong worded) opinion about the frameworks used and left the -helpful- answer. Yet, the post is now locked and in moderation to resolve the dispute. I was directed to meta by the only comment left visible.

Hence my question: How to deal with this best? Is it a good thing as an expert and long time user to intervene by editing the post, or is this unhelpful?

I would argue that preventing the drama while leaving the info would be the way to go.

Comment: It looks like the issue is currently **being** dealt with. Your job at this time is to sit back and await resolution.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understood that. I asked how to deal with this best. As a general question, giving an example that is currently being dealt with after I dealt with it already.

Comment: I really do like this edit explenation: _" replaced offensive language with teddy bears and cuddles"_

Comment: Quote: "Sorry for the snark. It's not aimed at you".  That was his get-out-of-jail card, he already edited out the f-words and did not engage in a rollback war.  No big deal.  Please unlock.

Comment: @HansPassant on the other hand, stackoverflow is rather clear in its intent. And that intent is not to share opinions on frameworks. That's why I edited it out. Not because I disagree with it, simple because it obscures the relevant information by angering a whole bunch of likewise opinionated people from the other side.

Comment: The post being locked doesn't mean you did something wrong. In fact, the moderator may very well have locked the post to pre-empt the possibility of the author rolling back your edit. The lock will expire after some time - for now, it's there to get everyone involved to take a step back and think of something else for a moment. Maybe teddy bears and cuddles. Maybe something else entirely.

Comment: @BoltClock thx for the info.

Comment: There is an interesting underlying question here about when strongly opinionated becomes *too* strongly opinionated. FWIW, I think opinionated answers are fine as long as the opinions aren't arbitrary and serve an useful purpose in setting up a factual answer. To mention a specific passage of the post we are discussing, I feel it is appropriate, in a context like this one, to say things like "For what it's worth, I think the tidyverse is an absolutely key part of modern R. But NSE is advanced, and people are delving into it before they are remotely ready".

Comment: @duplode There's a difference between being opinionated and being offensive. In fact it's not the same thing at all.

Comment: @lionel That is why I quoted a specific passage, rather than saying the whole post was fine in its original form. I thought that would have been enough to make a disclaimer unnecessary.

Comment: Offensive != opinionated. Please fix the title.

Comment: I see three reasons one *might* take issue with the original revision: Firstly, that it uses the word "f***" (asterisks in the original); secondly, that it expresses strong opinions about programming style; and thirdly, that it specifically criticises Hadley Wickam. Maybe those three points *interact* with each other (for instance, I'd be sympathetic to the view that swearing in answers is usually not a big deal, but that it should be curtailed in posts critical of specific individuals to make them less incendiary), but they're not the same; I'm concerned that they're being conflated, here.

Comment: @jpmc26. Merely stating "tidyeval is too complex for beginners" is enough to offend some people. Saying "tidyeval is solving a problem that shouldn't have been created in the first place" definitely does it. The only offensive part really was calling names at Hadley. All the rest was very strong worded opinion. So I focused on the main issue. The discussion in the comments should make that clear btw.

Comment: @MarkAmery fair points. Editing out the snark directed at Hadley was an obvious. It was the part where I edited out the (strong) opinions about tidyverse I wasn't sure about.

Comment: @JorisMeys I am talking about blatantly offensive remarks, not about harsh or potentially even unfair criticisms leveraged at the library itself. The problem here is that since such wording existed at one time, it is going to color any responses here. Note that [one of the site's most useful and popular answers of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1394393) is consists almost entirely of this kind of criticism.

Comment: @JorisMeys FWIW, I'm not sure I agree that editing out the references to Hadley was the right thing to do. Sometimes an idea's dominance comes purely from it being pushed by a single advocate who is highly persuasive or wields some kind of formal power. In that case, directly criticising them or their individual thought process in the course of criticising the idea seems defensible to me. Heck, I have a [highly-upvoted PHP answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31235907/1709587) whose entire thesis is essentially *"This misfeature only exists because Rasmus Lerdorf made a mistake of reasoning"*.

Comment: @jpmc26 offence is in the eye of the beholder. Which is why I prefer opinionated in the title. Not saying there was anything polite about the snark at Hadley. But it could count as an opinion as it is directed at the dev practices and communication from his team. So opinionated still seems more objective. And yes, I do understand why people take offence.

Comment: @MarkAmery I chose to remove everything that is merely opinion and not some reasoning behind the why of the answer. The references to Hadley didn't help the answer so hence were imho not needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @JorisMeys I guess that raises another point: should it be permissible for an answerer to use a narrow, practical question as an excuse to get on their soapbox and expound about a broader issue that the narrow question is exemplary of? I think the answer is "Yes - and let the *voters* judge whether the resulting commentary is relevant and useful, and downvote if they think it is not"... but you may disagree with that, too.

Comment: @MarkAmery I would disagree as votes on SO should be about helpfulness of the answer, not about what you think about the soapbox. SO is not Meta ;-) Actually, the voting war between the tidy-adepts and the tidy-critics was the direct trigger that led me to edit it out. I actually got drawn into it because one side used it as "a prime example of toxicity on SO". So I'm inclined to disagree and am convinced allowing this would quickly drag SO down to Yet Another Rant Collection.

Comment: @MarkAmery and Joris Meys: Perhaps the line lies between "expound[ing] about a broader issue" and using SO as a battleground for whatever internecine war currently afflicts your community. The problem, of course, is that, given a post that walks the line, people all too often fall prey to temptation, escalating instead of defusing.

Comment: (@JorisMeys It sadly underlines your point that this ordeal has apparently resulted in the answer author deleting their account. What a waste...)

Comment: The original answer was more of a rant than a technical article. As such it should probably be deleted rather than salvaged.

Comment: @MarkAmery it seems mods cannot undelete comments that are deleted by the community as R/A. I just learned something

Comment: Huh. I also had no idea there were any such limitations to your vast powers, @YvetteColomb. Well, deleting Hans's dangling half of our conversation, as you've done, is the second-best thing, I suppose.

Comment: @MarkAmery I got a smile reading them, particularly your second comment, next time, just use fake swearing. Hans wasn't insulted by it, it was a joke I thought. These are sensitive times :)

Comment: @duplode I wonder whether there was anything anyone could've done differently to prevent the user's ragequit. Did he ever see this Meta thread? Did he know that he could come here to argue his side, or did he think he'd had his post hijacked and then locked with no recourse available to him to get his name off it besides account deletion? If Yvette had commented on the answer after she locked it to encourage the answerer to come and weigh in on the argument here, would we have managed to keep him? Maybe, maybe, and maybe. It's too late to find out the answer to any of those questions, now.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You did the right thing.

Answers that are flagged as offensive often have their flags declined if the offensive content can be edited out by the community (AKA users like you) while leaving the meat of the answer intact, so good job on avoiding that common pitfall.

If you see a post get locked by moderators, especially in a circumstance like this, it's likely that the moderator is just ending (or preventing) a rollback war and freezing content in place while they mete out any appropriate punishments or perform necessary comment cleanups.

Speaking of comment cleanups, if you see a situation like this where people are fighting or flaming each other in the comments, definitely *do* flag them for moderator attention so that they can come in and defuse the situation.